# Python inheritance - One constructor that calls a method that's overriden in child classes, which method is used?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm writing a class in python that has multiple subclasses in it I have:

```
class Parent:

   def __init__(self, parameters):
      self.MethodA(parameters)

   def MethodA(parameters):
      doStuff

class child1(Parent):

   def MethodA(parameters):
      doOtherStuff
```

Which method will be used when I make an object of type child1?

Answer (score 3):

Try it and see:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.method(params)

    def method(self, params):
        print "Parent's method called with", params

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self, params):
        print "Child's method called with", params

Child('foo')
```

outputs:

> Child's method called with foo

Answer (score 1):

`child1.MethodA()` would be called. Methods in most dynamic languages are essentially always virtual since the lookup of `self` is done at runtime.

Comment: Its not the virtualness that matters here. If you try the same thing in C++ and have MethodA be virtual the Parent::MethodA will be called.

Answer (score 1):

It can be usefull for you - [method resolution order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Answer (score 0):

All methods in Python are effectively virtual.

```
>>> class Parent(object):
      def __init__(self):
            self.MethodA()

    def MethodA(self):
          print 'A method'

>>> class child1(Parent):
    def MethodA(self):
          print 'child1 method'

>>> x = child1()
child1 method
>>> x.MethodA()
child1 method
```